# Url cursor in a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

I have a cursor url and I want to change the cursor when it is on the button, I've tryed pointer, hover, url but it doesn't work can someone help me?
Thanks.

```
<button id="btt" style="cursor:hover" type="button">
```

The url I have:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body, a:hover {
        cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/games/gam-14/gam1379.ani), url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/games/gam-14/gam1379.png), progress !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is applying the cursor image to `<a>` elements and not buttons.

```
a:hover, button {
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/games/gam-14/gam1379.ani), 
          url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/games/gam-14/gam1379.png), 
          progress !important;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Comment: Gold! One question though, why use progress?

Comment: My guess is because the OP used it.